# Incremental text file processing for parallel processing

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm at the first experience with the Julia language, and I'm quite surprises by its simplicity.

I need to process big files, where each line is composed by a set of tab separated strings. As a first example, I started by a simple count program; I managed to use @parallel with the following code:

`d = open(f)
lis = readlines(d)
ntrue = @parallel (+) for li in lis
        contains(li,s)
end
println(ntrue)
close(d)
end`

I compared the parallel approach against a simple "serial" one with a 3.5GB file (more than 1 million lines). On a 4-cores Intel Xeon E5-1620, 3.60GHz, with 32GB of RAM, What I've got is:

> Parallel = 10.5 seconds; Serial = 12.3 seconds; Allocated Memory = 5.2
>   GB;

My first concern is about memory allocation; is there a better way to read the file incrementally in order to lower the memory allocation, while preserving the benefits of parallelizing the processing?
Secondly, since the CPU gain related to the use of @parallel is not astonishing, I'm wondering if it might be related to the specific case itself, or to my naive use of the parallel features of Julia? In the latter case, what would be the right approach to follow? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Your program is reading all of the file into memory as a large array of strings at once. You may want to try a serial version that processes the lines one at a time instead (i.e. streaming):

```
const s = "needle" # it's important for this to be const
open(f) do d
    ntrue = 0
    for li in eachline(d)
        ntrue += contains(li,s)
    end
    println(ntrue)
end
```

This avoids allocating an array to hold all of the strings and avoids allocating all of string objects at once, allowing the program to reuse the same memory by periodically reclaiming it during garbage collection. You may want to try this and see if that improves the performance sufficiently for you. The fact that `s` is `const` is important since it allows the compiler to predict the types in the for loop body, which isn't possible if `s` could change value (and thus type) at any time.

If you still want to process the file in parallel, you will have to open the file in each worker and advance each worker's read cursor (using the `seek` function) to an appropriate point in the file to start reading lines. Note that you'll have to be careful to avoid reading in the middle of a line and you'll have to make sure each worker does all of the lines assigned to it and no more – otherwise you might miss some instances of the search string or double count some of them.

If this workload isn't just an example and you actually just want to count the number of lines in which a certain string occurs in a file, you may just want to use the `grep` command, e.g. calling it from Julia like this:

```
julia> s = "boo"
"boo"

julia> f = "/usr/share/dict/words"
"/usr/share/dict/words"

julia> parse(Int, readchomp(`grep -c -F $s $f`))
292
```

Since the `grep` command has been carefully optimized over decades to search text files for lines matching certain patterns, it's hard to beat its performance. [Note: if it's possible that zero lines contain the pattern you're looking for, you will want to wrap the grep command in a call to the `ignorestatus` function since the `grep` command returns an error status code when there are no matches.]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The single processor version with the "const" trick, where `eachline(f)` should be changed in `eachline(d)`, does better than both the version with `@parallel` and `grep`: 8.5 seconds.  Nevertheless, I will need to do more complex stuff, for what I'd rather use parallelization. Is there a reference from where I can start from? Isn't `@parallel` supposed to split the array of strings between the workers in order to let them do the processing independently? Adding `addprocs(3)` makes memory increase a lot (I should exit the computation to avoid running out of memory).

Comment: I'm surprised (but pleased) that the efficient serial Julia version is faster than `grep`. Parallel processing adds overhead to each processor – you won't save on total memory usage since the data needs to be loaded somewhere. If you run across multiple machines, then you can access more total memory, but on a single system it's not a way to reduce memory usage.